# Webkit perspective transform cuts through another div

Tags: html, css, perspectives, css-transforms

A 3d rotated div cuts through another div with a higher z-index. I would like to prevent this, and force adherence to z-index definitions. I thought -webkit-transform-style: flat; would solve this. Anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not a fiddle so that we could look around this issue, but I can point you to a link which may be useful for you to figure out the issue:

http://css3.mikeplate.com/

Comment: Considering that link has no 3D transforms, that answer was not helpful at all.

Comment: that is why I said may be useful